# Which are the other best alternatives can we use other than lite-server in angular?

Tags: angular

*Acceptance Criteria

Find at least 2 alternatives to lite-server and
alternatives which i get should serve up code coverage UI.

Comment: Did this come straight from JIRA task description ;) ? This will be closed as off-topic. Maybe someone can comment the alternatives here.

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of options [http-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server) is most popular. [simplehttp2server](https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/simplehttp2server) is another great one if you want to test http2 locally

Comment: can u suggest still more i am not aware on this frontend part.

Comment: so will this also help for code coveraage UI also

Comment: can we use openresty for angular